# Show that $(\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x)\rightarrow (\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x)) $

Tags: logic

So here is what I have:

Assume $(\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x) $

Then by universal instantiation, $\alpha(t) \lor \beta(s)$.

Right here is where I am stuck. I'm stuck because the variables for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $t$ and $s$ respectively, so what allows me to use universal generalization to conclude $(\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x))$? I'm confused because the variables are different due to them being in different quantifer scopes.

Comment: Just consider two cases: 1) $(\forall x)\alpha(x)$ is true 2) $(\forall x)\beta(x)$ is true.

Comment: Your first assumption is correct, but note that you can't use universal instantiation because the main conective is a disjunction (I'm thinking in a natural deduction aproach here). What type of derivation do you need?

Comment: Can I not use universal instantiation on each predicate separately and then connect them with a disjunction? Actually no I cant, nevermind. This is for a class I'm taking, they want me to go through the logical steps and prove that this is true rigorously.

Comment: What rules are you allowed to use? What type of derivation do you want? If I take the natural dedcution aproach I have to use E∨, so it is not precise to say that you can just instantiate the formula (∀xAx) ∨ (∀xBx).

Comment: I am allowed to use all propositional and predicate equivalences as well as proof methods such as contrapositives, contradiction and etc. Maybe I could use contrapositive, which would let me do Existential Instantiation. I'm expected to be very rigorous and justify every single step of my argument citing an equivalence. I understand why I cannot use Universal Instantiation like I did in my post.

Comment: Proof by contrapositive. Assume $\exists x (\lnot\alpha(x) \land \lnot\beta(x))$. Then by Existential Instantiation, $\lnot\alpha(x) \land \lnot\beta(x)$. Applying Existential Quantification twice, we get $(\exists x)\lnot \alpha(x) \land (\exists x)\lnot\beta(x) $ and we are done.

Comment: Well, if you need to justify every single step natural deduction one of the best ways to do it. I can give you a naturale deduction derivation. Is this useful for you?

Comment: I think I figured it out with my contrapositive proof. I don't think there is a problem with it, could you check? It's in this comment thread.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that type of proof, so i can't help you with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) for justification
\begin{align}
& (\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x) \\
\iff & (\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall y)\beta(y) \\
\iff & (\forall y)((\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor \beta(y)) \\
\iff & (\forall x)(\forall y)(\alpha(x) \lor \beta(y))
\end{align}

In the last line if one takes the special case $x = y$, it implies the required formula.

Comment: I see how this works and why it does, but what allows me to go from the last step to $(\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x)) $ ?

Comment: Yes, I know why they are equivalent but how can I get it in the form that is in the title?

Comment: Ah yes I could just state that x = y and then make the substitution.

Comment: No it was very helpful thank you for taking the time to help me with my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The most straightforward proof (in a natural deduction system) will use ${\lor}E$ near the top level:

\begin{align*}
1.~ & (\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x) & & \mathrm{assumption} \\
2.~ & \quad (\forall x)\alpha(x) & & \mathrm{assumption} \\
& \quad\quad \vdots \\
N.~ & \quad\quad (\forall x) (\alpha(x) \lor \beta(x)) \\
N+1.~& \quad (\forall x)\beta(x) & & \mathrm{assumption} \\
& \quad\quad \vdots \\
M.~& \quad\quad (\forall x) (\alpha(x) \lor \beta(x)) \\
M+1.~& \quad(\forall x) (\alpha(x) \lor \beta(x)) & & {\lor}E ~ 1, 2-N, (N+1)-M \\
M+2.~& ((\forall x) \alpha(x) \lor (\forall x) \beta(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x) (\alpha(x) \lor \beta(x)) & & {\rightarrow}I ~ 1-(M+1)
\end{align*}
Now it's just left to you to fill in how you get from the assumption $(\forall x)\alpha(x)$ to the conclusion $(\forall x) (\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x))$, and similarly for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Disassemble the formula into the the truth conditional clauses for each connective step by step.

As you correctly figured out, to show the implication $(\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x)\rightarrow (\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x))$ we need to show that $(\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x))$ is true under the assumption that $(\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x)$ is true.

Now what is the case if $(\forall x)\alpha(x) \lor (\forall x)\beta(x)$ is true? By the semantics of $\lor$, either $(\forall x)\alpha(x)$ is true or $(\forall x)\beta(x)$ is true. So we do a proof by cases:

1. Assume $(\forall x)\alpha(x)$. That means for any term $t$, $\alpha(t)$ is true. With $\alpha(t)$ follows $\alpha(t) \lor \beta(t)$. Since the above  holds for any $t$, we have by universal generalization $(\forall x)(\alpha(x)\lor \beta(x))$.
2. Analogous (for you to fill in).

Since the succendent follows in any of the two cases, the implication holds.